# phpmyadmin not returning any records

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a strange issue when I input this query in phpmyadming:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.* FROM Events E, TICKET T WHERE ((E.idEvent=T.IDEvent  AND T.Email='david@fakesite.com')OR (E.email = 'david@fakesite.com')) AND E.dateEvent >= '2012-01-27 20:04:28' ORDER BY E.dateEvent ASC
```

I get not records, no errors found or anything, as if I've never made the query. I strongly beleive the query worked on phpmyadmin before, but now I can't seem to get it working locally or in the server. Two different machines, locally I have MAMP and in the server linux.

Strangest thing is that if the query is done by php, to the very same DB it returns the correct values.

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your current query risks returning a Cartesian product if T.email is not equal to 'david@air-ticket.com.es'.  That's the only part of the WHERE that contains your JOIN condition.

You should consider explicitly stating your JOIN and ON keywords like this (and then your WHERE clause becomes easier to understand):

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.*
FROM Events E
INNER JOIN TICKET T ON E.idEvent=T.IDEvent
WHERE (T.Email='david@air-ticket.com.es' OR E.email = 'david@myweb.com')
      AND E.dateEvent >= '2012-01-27 20:04:28' 
ORDER BY E.dateEvent ASC
```

And do both the Ticket and Events tables contain an email field?  Or is one of them a type-o?

For starters, give the above query a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but still same thing, nothing is returned or error are showed.
And yes, both tables contain email field